# How to move data of Email column from table A to Email column in B and return ID's of B to new column(EmaiID) as foreign key to table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I solved it by this solution :

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @emailRecordId INT
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT  id, email
FROM A
WHERE EmailId IS NULL;

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO B (Email) VALUES(@email)

    SET @emailRecordId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    UPDATE A SET EmailId = @emailRecordId where Email = @email
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @email

END;

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

But I need to rewrite it by more performance by one update statement without loop without one by one call.

Comment: If that solution worked, you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
INSERT INTO B (Email) 
    SELECT DISTINCT email 
    FROM A
    WHERE EmailId IS NULL;

UPDATE A
    SET EmailId = B.EmailId
    FROM A JOIN
         B
         ON A.email = B.email;
```

No cursor or loop is necessary.